# Serialize a message format to xml

Tags: python, xml, xml-serialization

I have a python list as

```
 [
     (A,{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}),
     B,{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}),
     ...
     ]
```

I want to know if there is a standard library of serializing this kind of list to xml or should I hand code it to a file.

Edit : Added Detail

Assuming this is used to construct a message such that

message = A( Feild attributes{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}) || B Field attributes{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}) || C Field attributes{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4})

Comment: You say you want to import it to Excel and hence it needs to be XML. Does it need to conform to a specific format, or can you provide XML of any format and work with it from there?

Comment: XML for import to Excel implies Excel's XML format. (*.xlsx)

Comment: Since Excel is involved... when you say `A` and `B`, are those supposed to be row labels?  Are `'a'`, `'b'`, etc. column labels?

Comment: Still no explanation that relates your `message = ` line to Excel or XML.

Comment: Okay A, B are supposed to be column labels, it is difficult to explain.

I did solve it myself to an extent but by handcoding the XML, which almost always is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"use json/yaml/whitespace" comments aside (I suppose you have your reasons to do so, instead go for pickle/json),

you can try the very pythonic elementtree library (in the standardlib), or even use some advice from google : search "converting python dictionary to xml"

(not to sound too rude .. take it with a wink)

looking at your example, what are A and B ? integers ? strings ? classmethods ?

Comment: :) I did check out the elementtree, 

This list gives out meta data from a class that describes a message
so A, B , C are fields of the message and the dictonary gives some values specific to the fields

Answer (score 4):

Does it need to be XML?  This is the usual domain of the `pickle` module.

But, no, there's no standard serialize-Python-object-to-XML library. (I have one I wrote a while ago, it's not published, much less "standard".)  There are libraries like `lxml` for converting XML to Python objects and back, and the usual `sax`, `dom`, and `expat` libraries for reading XML.

Comment: `pickle` is insecure and limited to use in a single language. There are almost always better serialization options.

Comment: `ElementTree` is really the nicest way to parse and write XML. In particular, for parsing it is a ton nicer than using `sax` or `dom`.

Comment: It is a message model, It needs to be exported to Excel hence the XML usage.

Comment: @anijhaw: Given that constraint, I can say there's no standard library.  I'm not even sure how your example constitutes a "message model".  If I were trying to import to Excel, I would use the `csv` library and then use Excel's CSV import.

Comment: @Mike: Security and language independence weren't specified, and the latter would require the input be more general than the Python list-of-tuples-with-dictionaries given.  `pickle` also does its job with very little implementation effort, much less than `ElementTree`, which is not a standard module.  That's why I was wondering why there was any need for XML... and here we are.

Comment: @Mike, 1) Security and robustness are good goals in most cases, especially the former. 2) I understand why you recommended not using XML if possible and agree; the contention remains that `ElementTree` is easier to use than the other *XML tools* you provided.

Answer (score 1):

- Why are you using XML? There are often better solutions, like JSON, which is plenty portable and standard.
- The easiest way might be to use YAML. YAML's main representation is not XML, but there is a canonical way (YAXML) to represent YAML serialized data as XML.